# Gravity form multi-select issue on ios

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have a multi-select field with a problem nobody has been able to solve.  This problem occurs when filling out the form using an iphone with chrome, firefox and safari browser apps. All multi- select fields have same problem. Seletion 'A' will not save unless its the only selection. If theres multiple selections the first selection (A) will not save but all others do.

See screenshots

[image][image]

Comment: This appears to be a support question and thus off-topic. Please ask at the Gravity Forms support forums.

Comment: I don't believe this is 'off-topic' for the following reasons. 1) Gravity no longer has 'support forums' so I assumed stack exchange could assist.  2) I actually hired someone with a Gravity Dev License to create the form.  3) This person is not around. 4) Only this person can contact support per new support system. 5) I contacted support and they told me to pay up $200 for a new license to have my question answered.

Comment: Questions regarding specific plugins are off-topic because they require extremely intimate knowledge of extremely niche and specialized code, meaning virtually none of the community can answer them, resulting in a frustrating experience for everyone involved. The best option is always the official support channels of the 3rd-party product. If you don't like the available support channels, it may be a good reason to find a new product. You might also seek help from more open-ended WordPress forums which don't conform to the StackExchange Q&A format.